# (Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).cycle is not a function) in Bknewsticker plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, plugins

The plugin does not work
This error will be displayed on the console
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).cycle is not a function

And was pointed to this line :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#bknewsticker').cycle({
speed: 1000,
timeout: 2000,
height: 40,
fx: 'slideX',
pause: 1,
containerResize: 1
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: do you actually have jQuery and cicle included in the right order ?

Comment: tnx
The problem was that you said.
With priority given to jQuery Fixed.

Comment: Than I would add as an answer so you can accept and mark s resolved .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in my first comment:

you might want to ensure that `jQUery` is included before any plugin that actually tries to use `jQuery` ( in your case - `cicle` ) .
Otherwise jQuery will not be available in the DOM when you try to evoke it, or any other script that use it as a dependency .

Comment: I have the same problem... I have checked in Network that the cycle.js is loaded properly and also I have tried running the .cycle() function inside the console of the browser and the same error occur which means that the order of inclusion its not the problem in this case. Any other ideas?

Comment: @raBne - The fact that you get the same error in the console does not mean that the order of inclusion is not the problem. You need to check for `jQuery` to load , and only then the `cycle.js`

Comment: Firstly, loading the jquery in console, then loading the cycle.js in console, and then executing the code also in console doesn't mean that the order of inclusion is not the problem?